# Laravel 9 mix : How to use async await componnent?

Tags: webpack, async-await, laravel-mix

I don't find anywere in the web someone to explain how to add exoperiment await componnent to laravel mix.

My error :

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/departements_search.js
Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

I found this :

```js
module.exports = {
    //...
    experiments: {
      asyncWebAssembly: true,
      buildHttp: true,
      layers: true,
      lazyCompilation: true,
      outputModule: true,
      syncWebAssembly: true,
      topLevelAwait: true,
    },
};
```

But I don't understand how to setup ? My webpack.config seem not working at all. How to add this feature like :

```js
mix.webpackConfig({
  // something here
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `webpack.mix.js`, add this:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    // ... existing stuff (optional)
    ,
    experiments: {
        topLevelAwait: true
    }
```